# Sorting an array of strings alphabetically

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, java-7

I have written the following working code. I believe it could be made better or more efficient but I'm not too sure how to go on about it.

The main thing that I'm unhappy with is the three replaces.

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < user.getTasks().size(); i++) {
    test.add(user.getTasks.get(i).getTask().toString());
}
Collections.sort(test);
System.out.println(test.toString().replace(",", " |").replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
```

The output is something like follows: Tast1 | Task2 | Task3 and it is good.

Please don't hesitate to ask any questions, I'm super responsive.

Comment: You could use a regular expression and Pattern : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're unhappy with? If you're looking for general code improvement advice, mabve try [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Java 7 and streams are not available, you can:

1. use the simpler `for` syntax (assuming `user.getTasks()` returns a list of `Task` objects - replace `Task` with your class if not)
2. loop through the strings, concatenating them with the separator

---

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (Task task : user.getTasks()) {
    test.add(task.getTask().toString());
}
Collections.sort(test);

// make a string of the values with a pipe separator
StringBuilder valuesToPrint = new StringBuilder();
for (int index = 0; index < test.size(); index++) {
    if (index > 0) {
        valuesToPrint.append(" | ");
    }
    valuesToPrint.append(test);
}

System.out.println(valuesToPrint.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is exactly what I would want but unfortunately I'm using Java 7. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Edited to show how to join strings without using a stream.

Comment: Thank you again! I like this better than what I previously had

Comment: Edited to use simpler `for` syntax.

Comment: `String.join(…)` is a Java 8 method.

Comment: @DaveDaBest If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8+ you could simplify it as:

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(); 
String result = user.getTasks().stream()
                               .map(t -> t.getTask().toString())
                               .sorted()
                               .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
System.out.println(result);
```

Which will create a `Stream` of the `String`'s in the list, sort them, and then join them into a `String` with `|` in between each item

Or if you need to do other operations on the sorted list, you could sort it and then do the stream part after:

```
Collections.sort(test);
String result = test.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Java 7. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: When you use streams, use them consistently, i.e. `String result = user.getTasks().stream().map(t -> t.getTask().toString()).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining("|"));`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, Java 8 `Stream` API provides a lot of utilities to perform those kind of tasks, but if you want to keep your solution using loops and you want to avoid the three replaces, instead of calling `toString()` on the list and then cleaning it up, you should loop the items on the list while building a `String`

```
String result = "";
for (String item : test) {
    result += item + " | ";
}
System.out.println(result.substring(0, result.length() - 3);
```

Note that you print the result cutting out the last three characters to avoid printing Tast1 | Task2 | Task3 `|`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Java 7. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The code provided for the String building is valid for Java7, but you should check Jason's response. `String.join` is much more concise and clean. Take my response only as a manual way of doing the same.

Comment: There is no way around this manual way of doing the same, as `String.join` is also a Java 8 method, even if it doesn’t use streams. But I’d consider using a `StringBuilder`.